# How to compare two savepoints programmatically?

Tags: java, jdbc, transactions, savepoints

I want to compare two Savepoints and check if there were any commits to the database in between. For example, consider the following code snippet

```
 Savepoint save1 = connection.setSavePoint("before);
 // some processing happens here, which can commit some changes to the DB.
 process();
 Savepoint save2 = connection.setSavePoint("after");

 // Now compare the two savepoints to see if there were any commits in process() method
```

Now what I am trying to explore is: Is there a way by which I can programmatically check if there were any commits between the two savepoints?

Comment: There is no such functionality. A savepoint is just an intermediate step in a transaction that you can rollback to without rolling back the entire transaction.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. Is there any other way by which I can check if any commit did happen in process()? process() can be considered as a black box method.

Comment: Well, maybe you could proxy or wrap the `Connection` and intercept the call to `commit()`?

Answer (score 1):

Posting a solution to my question which worked for me.

I used the fact that the savepoint will get flushed out if there is any commit operation after it. Hence, rolling back to that same savepoint would throw an error that the savepoint was never established. If it successfully got rolled back, that would mean there was no commit operation in between.

Answer (score 0):

The most simplest way would be having a [Stack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) object where you push current operation something like `DBOperationStack.push(new String[]("OPERATION_TYPE", "OPERATION_NAME", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))`.
*[This is plain pseudo-code, change data-structure, scope, concurrency etc.]*

You can add above line wherever required for database operation.

When you reach to **savepoint_2**, `peek` from the stack & check if it's **savepoint_1**, if it's not, then there might be some operations in between them like update, insert etc. the most recent one.

```
COMMIT,    PROCESS_XYZ, 2016-01-29 15:03:08.713
SAVEPOINT, SAVEPOINT_1, 2016-01-29 15:02:08.713
```